# How to manipulate unity camera in a C# script?

Tags: unity, movement

I am new to unity and i'm trying to move the camera to follow the player, but everything i tried won't work. Please explain what each step is and show code. I want to add to its position not use translate.

Comment: This is a very low-quality question, because it doesn't describe what "everything i tried" might be, or in what way it "won't work." Moreover, it's not clear what is meant by "add to its position not use translate," since a change in position is called a translation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Camera Follow">

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

private Vector2 velocity;
public float smoothTimeX; 
public float smoothTimeY;
public GameObject player; 


void Start () 
{

}


void FixedUpdate () 
{
    float posX = Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.x, player.transform.position.x, ref velocity.x, smoothTimeX);
    float posY = Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.y, player.transform.position.y, ref velocity.y, smoothTimeY);

    transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY , transform.position.z);
}
```

}

Comment: It would be nice of you to comment and describe the script you posted because not doing that will encourage the question asker to simply copy and paste the source code.